# mysql - can I constrain a field to some predefined values without foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database

In mysql I have a `companies` table, and I want to add a field called `relationship_type` and to assign to it some predefined values like:

```
"customer" , "supplier" , "partner" , "potential customer", "friend" ,
"competitor" , ... etc
```

I don't want the database to accept any strange value in this field except of these values. the way I know that I can accomplish what I want is by using "foreign keys" , by creating **new table** call it `relationships` and make a foreign key constraint , but I think this is a bad and wasting-tables way as in this example:

```
companies table:
+----------+-----+-------+----------------+
|company_id|Name |address|relationship(FK)|
+----------+-----+-------+----------------+
|0         | A   |place1 |customer        |
+----------+-----+-------+----------------+
|1         | b   |place2 |supplier        |
+----------+-----+-------+----------------+

relationship table:
+-----------------+
|relationship(PK) |
+-----------------+
|customer         |
+-----------------+
|supplier         |
+-----------------+ 
|partner          |
+-----------------+ 
|competitor       |
+-----------------+
```

also I don't want to handle these constrains programmatically in the client applications that will use the database, for example I don't want to check in my PHP code for this value when the user inserts it to the database, because I may miss something any place in my application that let the user insert some different values in the field , ending up with inconsistent data like `customer` and `CUSTOMER`.

**Is there a way to let the database handle these constrains without foreign keys?** *and please consider that I'm very newbie.* thanks

Comment: don't consider it a waste. what if you needed to add a new relationship?

Comment: Although you can use other methods (`enum` and triggers come to mind), a reference table with a foreign key is probably the best method.

Comment: I'd say use `enum`. If the list is fixed I wouldn't take the overhead of an additional relation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff @Daniel A. White , thank you , so it is normal in real life databases to have small tables like this `relationships` table? , if yes. what about fields like male, female or fields with 3 values? do I create separate tables for them too?

Comment: @theaccountant . . . In other databases, you can use a `check` constraint, but MySQL does not enforce those.